# How to use android-undergarment library

Tags: android, android-widget, slidingdrawer, slidingmenu

I am trying to use the android-undergarment library to create a side menu but I don't seem to be able to figure out how to add items to the listview layout I supplied to the constructor. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally found out how to do it.

```
ListView view = (ListView)mDrawerGarment.findViewById(R.id.sideMenuList);
    List<String> menuItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    menuItems.add("One");
    menuItems.add("two");
    menuItems.add("three");
    menuItems.add("four");
```